# Just Transferred Schools - What to list on resume

Tags: resume

I just transferred colleges. However, I remain enrolled at the previous institution until the end of June. How should I list this on my resume? I don't have a GPA yet at the transferring institution as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I would list them separately and put the intended start and end dates for each, even though they are in the future.  If you're concerned that they might not see that it's a future date you could put (planned) after each date.